# Clang unexpected TranslationUnit as CXCursor parent's kind

Tags: c++, clang

I am currently just trying to figure out how to parse code using clang.
I've built a simple walker to print what is going on, but I am getting unexpected results.

My walker:

```
int main()
{
  CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
  CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
    index,
    "parseMe.hpp", nullptr, 0,
    nullptr, 0,
    CXTranslationUnit_None);
  CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(unit);
  Walker::visitNode(cursor);
}

void Walker::visitNode(CXCursor cursor){
    clang_visitChildren(cursor,
    [](CXCursor c, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data)
    {
        printf("\nKind: %s\n", clang_getCString(clang_getCursorKindSpelling(clang_getCursorKind(c))));
        printf("Identifier: %s\n", clang_getCString(clang_getCursorSpelling(c)));
        printf("Parent Kind: %s\n", clang_getCString(clang_getCursorKindSpelling(clang_getCursorKind(parent))));
        printf("Parent Identifier: %s\n\n", clang_getCString(clang_getCursorSpelling(parent)));
        return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
    },
    nullptr);
}
```

The code I'm trying to parse (parseMe.hpp):

```
class MyClass
{
  namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyNestedClassInsideNamespace {
      int myNestedFieldInsideNamespace;
    };
  }

  class MyNestedClass {
    int myNestedField;
  };

public:
  int field;
};
```

The result I get tells me that `MyNestedClass` and `MyNamespace`'s parent is the `TranslationUnit` instead of the expected `ClassDecl` and the identifier is the name of the file `parseMe.hpp` instead of `MyClass`:

```
Kind: ClassDecl
Identifier: MyClass
Parent Kind: TranslationUnit
Parent Identifier: parseMe.hpp


Kind: Namespace
Identifier: MyNamespace
Parent Kind: TranslationUnit
Parent Identifier: parseMe.hpp


Kind: ClassDecl
Identifier: MyNestedClassInsideNamespace
Parent Kind: Namespace
Parent Identifier: MyNamespace


Kind: FieldDecl
Identifier: myNestedFieldInsideNamespace
Parent Kind: ClassDecl
Parent Identifier: MyNestedClassInsideNamespace


Kind: ClassDecl
Identifier: MyNestedClass
Parent Kind: TranslationUnit
Parent Identifier: parseMe.hpp


Kind: FieldDecl
Identifier: myNestedField
Parent Kind: ClassDecl
Parent Identifier: MyNestedClass


Kind: UnexposedDecl
Identifier:
Parent Kind: TranslationUnit
Parent Identifier: parseMe.hpp
```

Can someone explain these unexpected (by me) results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I forgot that C++ doesn't allow namespaces inside classes. Having removed the namespace showed the expected results.